# How to test and mock a GRPC service written in Java using Mockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, grpc

The protobuf definition is as follows:

```
syntax = "proto3";

package helloworld;

// The greeting service definition.
service Greeter {
  // Sends a greeting
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply) {}
}

// The request message containing the user's name.
message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

// The response message containing the greetings
message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

I need to use Mockito along with JUnit testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The idea is to stub the response and stream observer.

```
@Test
public void shouldTestGreeterService() throws Exception {

    Greeter service = new Greeter();

    HelloRequest req = HelloRequest.newBuilder()
            .setName("hello")
            .build();

    StreamObserver<HelloRequest> observer = mock(StreamObserver.class);

    service.sayHello(req, observer);

    verify(observer, times(1)).onCompleted();

    ArgumentCaptor<HelloReply> captor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(HelloReply.class);

    verify(observer, times(1)).onNext(captor.capture());

    HelloReply response = captor.getValue();

    assertThat(response.getStatus(), is(true));
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Selvaram. This helped a lot. Only I have to edit **StreamObserver<HelloReply> observer = mock(StreamObserver.class);** as I have defined the method like that.

Answer (score 7):

The encouraged way to test a service is to use the in-process transport and a normal stub. Then you can communicate with the service like normal, without lots of mocking. Overused mocking produces brittle tests that don't instill confidence in the code being tested.

`GrpcServerRule` uses in-process transport behind-the-scenes. We now  I suggest taking a look at the examples' tests, starting with [hello world](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldServerTest.java).

Edit: We now recommend `GrpcCleanupRule` over `GrpcServerRule`. You can still reference the hello world example.

Comment: I did the tests as suggested by Selvaram, after I read Eric's comment I thought it was pertinent, but if I use the "in-process transport and a normal stub" wouldn't I be doing an integration test somehow?

At the same level as the recommended test, there is another test like the Selvaram proposed.

https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/blob/master/examples/src/test/java/io/grpc/examples/helloworld/HelloWorldClientTest.java

Comment: See https://testing.googleblog.com/2013/05/testing-on-toilet-dont-overuse-mocks.html . The reason grpc-java encourages uses the in-process transport is to avoid "Tests can provide less assurance that your code is working properly." Early in gRPC's life users were using mocks, and the tests provided no real value yet caused impossible conditions; they were purely harmful. The in-process transport provides most of the advantages of mocks without the downfalls, including being able to execute the test deterministically on a single thread.